# Can't change text color in CSS coding

Tags: css

```
<style>
p   {
       color: red;
   }
</style>
```

I'm doing what ever is my tutorial-video doing.
why it doesn't change my paragraph color in my code?
not only paragraph, but headings an so on... when I run the code, the whole page is written by Black!
and I'm using Aptana Studio.
what can be the problem of?
I'm a beginner :/

Comment: try to use `!important` : `color: red!important;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you put this code between `<style></style>` like this?

```
<style>
p   {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Are your paragraph properly formatted like this?

```
<p>Your Text!</p>
```

If still not working, try this:

```
<style>
p   {
    color:red !important;
}
</style>

<p>Your Text!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add some unique id/class to your paragraph and style that by id.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfect:

```css
p   {
       color:red;
   }
```

```html
<p>Try me</p>
```

**The only reason is that your css override by other defination**:

**to solve** this issuse you can use `!important` but do it **carefully**, learn here:https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

You can put this css before all style and see in F12 if it overriden and where to perevent it!

**See here how definetion override in css** (F12)

[image]

Comment: tell me for more help!

Answer (score -2):

```
      Actually style for <p> is may be already define
    so look this example 

    you will get hole idea 
    how to get highest priority in css 
    add **!important** in front of tag 

it will get highest priority
```

```css
    
    p{
color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   
    </head>
    <body>
    
  
    
    <p>This is an  paragraph..</p>
    
   
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This should work.